# Was/were comes with 2nd form or first?

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

How was is used in sentences with first form or with second ?

For example what is correct:
I was not fractured ?
or 
I was not fracture ?

Similarly in another example:
I was failed or I was fail ?

Will same for verbal and written English ?

Thanks

Comment: *I was failed* is marginally acceptable English--"I was failed by the examiners"--but *I was fractured* is very odd. What exactly are you trying to express with that sentence?

Comment: @StoneyB I went for x-ray of my chest and luckily I was not fractured.

Comment: Ah. We usually speak of bones being broken rather than people, so "Luckily nothing was broken" or "Luckily I didn't have anything broken" would be more usual.

Answer (score 2):

"First" and "second" form are not technical terms with a fixed meaning in English grammar; I take it that what you mean is what are generally called the "present" and "past" forms.

If that is the case, then I must tell you that **neither** of these forms is employed in the passive construction. The form you want is the "past participle". This is often confusing for learners, because with the majority of English verbs (including *fracture* and *fail*) the "past" and "past participle" forms are identical, formed with the suffix *-(e)d*; but in many very common verbs they are different. For instance, a more common synonym for *fracture* is *break*, and that has distinct past and past participle forms:

```
 PLAIN FORM     PAST FORM     PAST PARTICIPLE FORM
 fracture       fractured     fractured   
 break          broke         broken
```

The passive construction is constructed from a form of *BE* + the past participle; for instance:

```
 I    am/was    broken/fractured/failed.      
 He   is/was    broken/fractured/failed.
 They are/were  broken/fractured/failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your examples:

*I was not fractured* is correct whereas *I was not fracture* is wrong.  **Since 'was' is past-tense, the verb would have to be past tense as well.**  Fractured is past tense and fits with 'was'.

The same situation applies to your second example.  "I was failed" is correct and "I was fail" is incorrect.  *Failed* is past tense just like *was*.

Although I am not sure what you are trying to convey with your first example.  "I was not fractured" does not exactly make sense.  Do you mean to say, "**I was not hurt**" or "**I was not injured**", perhaps?

Comment: thanks, I m really confuse about it. Lets take another example:
I was correct (at this stage of time I m telling about something in past that I was correct). Should it be I was corrected ? I m just considering how you explained "was" is past-tense, the verb would have to be past tense as well.

Comment: by "I was not fractured" I m referring something I went for X-Ray and luckily I was not fractured.

Comment: @user576510 In *I was correct*, you are using *correct* as an adjective, not a verb, so it does not inflect at all. *I was corrected* means "Somebody corrected me" -- that is "I made a mistake and somebody pointed out how I should do it correctly".

Comment: Stoney is correct.  "Correct" is not being used as a verb in your example.  You could say "I was not correct" but "correct" isn't something that actual happened, like with "fractured".